# java multiple servlets thread safety of hashtable

Tags: java, servlets, thread-safety, hashtable, shared

in my application, i have one servlet which performs login and other operations.
in this single servlet i store the users in an hastable keyed by the session id.

```
Hashtable<string,MySession> sessions; //sessionid and MySession instance
```

But the login process is a bit complicated and contains business issues, so i decided it to seperate, i want to have two servlets one for **login** and one for **operation**. The login servlet will generate MySession and will store it and forward the client to the **operation** servlet. As a result the both servlets **login** and **operation** must share this hashtable.

Question is,

- is my current structure threadsafed? I mean this single servlet instance, where i store all users in a hastable? I have hashtable modifying methods such as addNewSession and clearSession. (I use browser session id as key). I did not make this methods synchronised, because this approach is not suggested (single instance of servlet)
- what happens if i declare this hastable static so i can reach it from both new separated servlets (login and operation)
- what if i store this hastable in a parent servlet and extend login and operation from that servlet so that both can reach their parent servlets protected hashtable instance?
- using servlet contenxt methods, where i reach the other servlet from context or directly store the hashtable in context? Will it resolve thread safety issuses? Or i think i should
  provide synchronization for ServletContext object returned by getServletContext() because it is shared between servlets in myapplication?

The current structure is:

```
public SingleServlet extends HttpServlet {
     Hashtable<string,MySession> sessions = new Hashtable();

     public void doGet(HttpRequest request, HttpResponsr response) {
         String sessionId = request.getSessionId();

         if (sessions.get(sessionId) == null) {
             // Create a new session and store
             // Do login operations
             MySession iNewSession = new MySession(..);

             // Thread safety??
             sessions.put(sessionId, iNewSession);
         } else {
             // Already existing session, operate on that
             MySession iExistingSession = sessions.get(sessionId);

             // Check if operation is logout
             if (isLogout(request)) {
                iExistingSession.performLogout();

                // Thread safety??
                sessions.remove(sessionId);
             } else
             iExistingSession.continueOperation(request, response);
         }
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing what the native sessions already do?

Comment: you mean apache shiro?

Comment: No, I mean HttpSession. That's exactly what it is: a hash table for each session ID, where you can store any attribute you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not thread-safe.  While individual operations (like `put`, `get` and `remove`) are atomic and thread-safe, a sequence of operations (e.g. a `get` followed by a `put`) is not thread-safe.

Comment: I believe ConcurrentHashMap under java.util.concurrent is a better choice than Hashtable since 1.5, but would it solve the problem in this case? Or do you have any other suggestions?